# Ajax autocompleteextender calling webservice to search from 2 fields of database, its working now

Tags: asp.net, sql, ajax, web-services, autocomplete

I m using ajax autocomplete which calls a web service to search name and code(name & code are fields of my datatable)

It works fine

this is my webmothod of webservice

```
   [WebMethod]
        public string[] GetSupplier(string prefixText)
        {
            con.Open();
            //int count = 10;
            string sql = "Select * from SupplierMaster where name like @prefixText  ";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = prefixText + "%";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            string[] List = new string[100];
            int i = 0;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                List.SetValue(dr["name"].ToString(), i);
                i++;
            }

         string sql1 = "Select * from SupplierMaster where codelike @prefixText  ";
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, con);
            da1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = prefixText + "%";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da1.Fill(dt);
            string[] List = new string[100];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                List.SetValue(dr["name"].ToString(), i);
                i++;
            }
            con.Close();
            return List;

        }
```

and this is autocomplete extender in .aspx file

```
  <asp:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="AutoCompleteExtender3" TargetControlID="txtsear" ServicePath="~/Search.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetSupplier"

 MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="10" 
CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
 CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
                                                                    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
 </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: is it working with just the name field, and now you want to add the code, or is it not working at all, even just with the name field only, as above?

Comment: I haved edited its correct & is working.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11340534/1445836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer,

```
  [WebMethod]
        public string[] GetSupplier(string prefixText)
        {
            con.Open();
            //int count = 10;
            string sql = "Select * from SupplierMaster where name like @prefixText";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = prefixText + "%";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            string[] List = new string[100];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                List.SetValue(dr["name"].ToString(), i);
                i++;
            }

            string sql1 = "Select * from SupplierMaster where code like @prefixText";
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, con);
            da1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = prefixText + "%";
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            da1.Fill(dt1);
            //string[] List = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            //int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
            {
                List.SetValue(dr["code"].ToString(), i);
                i++;
            }
            con.Close();
            return List;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it, adapted for your table/fields:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
// your class/namespace etc.

[WebMethod]
public List<string> GetSupplier(string prefixText)
{
    string SQL = "Select * from SupplierMaster where name like '%" + prefixText.Replace("'", "''") + "%' ";

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringGoesHere);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, cnn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    List<string> returnvalues = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            returnvalues.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
    }

    return returnvalues;
}
```

I took the liberty of prefixing your search text AND suffixing it with a wildcard `%` sign; you might not want that.

Now, if you want to search BOTH fields, you can use:

```
    string SQL = "Select * from SupplierMaster where name like '%" + prefixText.Replace("'", "''") + "%' OR code like '%" + prefixText.Replace("'", "''") + "%' ";
```

**edit**

From your own answer, I see you're combining the code & name fields. I would prefer to do it with my shorter code above, but with a UNION query, like so:

```
string SQL = "Select name from SupplierMaster where name like '%" + prefixText.Replace("'", "''") + "%' UNION Select code from SupplierMaster where code like '%" + prefixText.Replace("'", "''") + "%' ";
```